# Kroenecker product

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

When taking the kroenecker product of two matrices it should hold that $A\otimes B$ is unitarily equivalent to $B \otimes A$ but I can't figure out what this unitary matrix would look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $A \otimes B$ and $B \otimes A$ can only be guaranteed to be unitarily similar if both $A$ and $B$ are square.

So, suppose $A$ is $n \times n$ and $B$ is $m \times m$. It suffices to build a matrix $P$ such that $P(x \otimes y) = y \otimes x$ for all $x \in \Bbb C^n, y \in \Bbb C^m$.  In this case, we find that for all such $x,y$ we have
$$
P (A \otimes B)P^{-1}(y \otimes x) = P(A \otimes B)(x \otimes y) = P(Ax \otimes By) = By \otimes Ax
$$
so that $P (A \otimes B)P^{-1} = B \otimes A$.

We can build $P$ explicitly as follows: Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote the canonical basis of $\Bbb C^n$.  We can build the necessary permutation matrix $P$ by taking as the columns of $P$ the vectors $e_i \otimes e_j$ with $e_i \in \Bbb C^m, e_j \in \Bbb C^n$, and the tuples $(j,i)$ taken in lexicographical order.

In the case where $m=n$ we find that $P^* = P$, which is to say that $P$ is Hermitian (symmetric) in addition to being a permutation matrix.

As an example: for the case of $n=3,m=2$, we find that
$$
P = [e_1^{(2)} \otimes e_1^{(3)}, e_2^{(2)} \otimes e_1^{(3)},\dots]
= 
\left[\begin{array}{cc|cc|cc}
1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0\\
\hline
0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{array}\right]
$$

Comment: Note: this permutation matrix is sometimes referred to as the [Commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) $P = \mathbf K^{(m,n)}$.

Answer (score 3):

Not only are they unitarily equivalent, they are Permutation similar. There exists a permutation matrix $P$ such that 
$$P (A\otimes B) P^\top = B \otimes A$$