# linking two non-square matrices reshaped in row-wise and column-wise

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Assume I have a matrix X whose dimension is (32,8). That matrix is reshaped into X1 = (256,1) but in row-wise, it means starting the first row then second row and so on. On the other hand, if matrix X was reshaped into X2 = (256,1) too, but column-wise, it means starting first columns, then second column and so on.

My question, if we can write X1 = PX2, where P is a permutation matrix, What should be the matrix P?

NP: In case if the matrix X is square, It's clear that we can write P as below matlab code:

```
function p(v)
%v = vectorsize, in your case 16
for k=1:v^2
for n = 1:v^2
    p(k,n)=0;
end;
end;
for i=1:v
for j = 1:v
    k=v* (i-1) + j;
    n=v* (j-1) + i;
    p(k,n)=1;
end;
end;
```

The issue I'm facing now is how to deal with that when the matrix X is not square, as I mentioned, it's for example of size (32,8), how should it be?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you mention your previous question 2 days ago (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3580612) about the square case ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I'm working on issues related to that question. Everyday I get results I face another related issue. I mean it's not mathematical issue, I'm just using that multiplication. Of course, I don't mind to delete one of posts.  and sorry for that repetition.

Comment: A general rule in research (even at a small scale) is to (give/look for) maximal information in order you and others do not reinvent the wheel (and lose much time)

Comment: @JeanMarie .. OK thank you so much for your advise .. that's really appreciated

Comment: You know, however with people who have less experience, that's not easy to follow that rules, but let's try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), we have
$$
X_1 = \sum_{i,j=1}^{m,n}  x_{ij}\,e_i \otimes f_j, \quad 
X_2 = \sum_{i,j=1}^{m,n}  x_{ji}\,f_j \otimes e_i,
$$
where $e_i,f_i$ denote the $i$th column of the $m \times m$ and $n \times n$ identity matrices respectively. For your case, we have $m = 32$ and $n = 8$.

As it turns out, the permutation matrix satisfying $PX_1 = X_2$ can be written as
$$
P = \sum_{i,j = 1}^{m,n} [e_j \otimes e_i][e_i \otimes f_j]^T
= \sum_{i,j = 1}^{m,n} (f_je_i^T) \otimes (e_if_j^T)
= \sum_{i,j = 1}^{m,n} (E_{ij})^T \otimes E_{ij}
$$
where $E_{ij}$ denotes the $m \times n$ matrix with a $1$ in the $ij$ entry, and zeros everywhere else.

---

This sum formula can be directly implemented in matlab if you use the `kron` function.

Here's a script that uses another approach to build to build $P$; you might find this approach a bit more intuitive.

```
P = zeros(m*n)
col = 1;
for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:n
        E = zeros(m,n);
        E(i,j) = 1;
        P(:,col) = E(:);
        col = col + 1;
    end
end
```

Note that this $P$ is sometimes called a [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.  I notices something in the resulted matrix P. That in every column, all values are zeros except one value equals to 1. Is there logical explanation for that ?

Comment: @Gze Yes: the logical explanation is that this is true for *every* permutation matrix

Comment: Could you please add some details about that. and is that one of every column is located in a determined location or randomly ?

Comment: @Gze details about what exactly?  The definition of a permutation matrix?  Perhaps you should take a look through the [relevant wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix).

Comment: @Gze Since the formula and script are deterministic, it doesn't really make sense to say that the location of a one in a given column is "random".  If you want a systematic description: the $(n(i-1) + j)$th column as a one as its $(m(j-1) + i)$th entry.

Comment: @Gze Per the definition of a permutation matrix, each row and column contains exactly one $1$.  Consequently, no two columns will have a $1$ in the same location.

Comment: OK .. Thank you so much.  that's clear enough

Comment: @Gze I found [this old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3308432/81360) of mine that writes the permutation matrix out nicely; maybe that will help you get a better feeling for what's going one

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way is to permute the columns of identity matrix $I_{mn}$ in a rather natural manner :

> ```
> m=32;n=8;
> r=n*m;
> I=eye(r);
> J=mod(m*(0:(r-2)),r-1)+1;
> P=I(:,[J,r]);
> ```
>
> Test on random matrices :
>
> ```
> M=rand(m,n);N=M';
> max(abs(P*N(:)-M(:))), %is zero
> ```